# How to flatten a nested object?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have the following nested object:

```
[
{
    "id": "b2dgd67e7e7",
    "fields": {
        "task1": "task 1",
        "task2": "task 2"
    }
},
 {
    "id": "b2dgd67e7e8",
    "fields": {
        "task1": "task 3",
        "task2": "task 4"
    }
}
]
```

I would like to flatten it to the following format bellow:...........................................

```
[
{

    "fields": {
        "task1": "task 1",
        "task2": "task 2",
        "id": "b2dgd67e7e7",
    }
},
 {

    "fields": {
        "task1": "task 3",
        "task2": "task 4",
        "id": "b2dgd67e7e8",
    }
}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you need a generic function or a specific function

Comment: @bryan60 generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on your array to build a new array of mapped objects. To map each object, you can [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the `id` and `fields` property from the object, and then return a new object which contains your `fields` property along with the original contents of the `fields` object value as well as the remaining outside properties (such as id):

```js
const arr = [{ "id": "b2dgd67e7e7", "fields": { "task1": "task 1", "task2": "task 2" } }, { "id": "b2dgd67e7e8", "fields": { "task1": "task 3", "task2": "task 4" } } ];

const flattenToKey = (arr, key) => 
  arr.map(({[key]: k, ...r}) => ({[key]: {...k, ...r}}));

const res = flattenToKey(arr, 'fields');
console.log(res);
```